# Share access to a network drive with other users on the same Windows machine

Tags: windows, networking, file-sharing, server-message-block

I am using `net use` to mount network drives. Of course they are only visible to the current user. I am wondering is it possible to share the drive with other users? What I am trying to achieve is to mount the network drive from one service user to other service users (and maybe interactive users).

Comment: It is possible using the SYSTEM account, but usually there's a better option, like: why don't you just mount it per user? Is this some RDS environment or equivalent?

Comment: @Lenniey mounting per user is possible but I have to impersonate those users which is a bit of pita. I don't know if there is a `sudo -S -u otheruse` in Windows, but I looked around into impersonation on Windows and all solutions were rather cumbersome.

Comment: You don't need impersonation, you can always map the share on user-login, for example. Or create a script on the user's desktop, etc. etc.

Comment: @Lenniey that's a good option, thought I would rather control everything from one place.

Comment: What's with GPOs/ GPPs?

Comment: @Lenniey woooah, mind=blow. I had no idea that was possible. Yeah actually that would be the most convenient option, although local service users are not domain users, but that I can fix. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using GPOs and/ or GPPs.